# Disable button upon form submit

Tags: php, forms

I made a BlackJack game using only php, and html of course for the layout. But what im trying to say is I need to only use PHP. So no javascript or something else.

My game is near completion, all that's left is the buttons.

I have 3 buttons, Start, Hit and the Stand button. These buttons work with forms, If you click Start it will submit a form where the player draws 2 cards and the dealer 1. Then if you click hit it submits a form where the page will give you 1 card. And by clicking Stand it lets the dealer play, drawing cards untill he hits => 17.

I hope you understand how my system works. (If not please tell me!)

Now when i start the program all buttons except Start needs to be disabled, when i submit the start form (Click the start button) it needs to disable the start button and enable all the others. I find this complicated to achieve since I've never done anything like this before without javascript.

I tried the following:

`if (!isset($_SESSION["buttons"])){$_SESSION["buttons"]='disabled';}`

This runs at the very start of the form, and in the buttons i echo the session out, so when i start it for the first time it disables all buttons, this works fine.

But when i click start, and run this:

```
if(FORM_start("Start")){
    buttons();
}
```

And buttons(); being the following:

```
function buttons() {
   $_SESSION["buttons"] = '';
}
```

It doesn't work the first time i click on Start, however if i click start again the other buttons get enabled suddenly.

So this way seems to work, only i need to press start twice, meaning i got 4 cards and the dealer 2.

Is there any way i can let it happen immediately or maybe there is some other way to disable/enable buttons using only PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use js?

Comment: This is perfect for javascript, but since you don't want to use it.  Have you considered just not drawing the buttons?  Since PHP is serving the webpage, can't you have it just not serve the button portion?

Comment: You need to edit the HTML of your buttons to enable/disable them

Comment: Do you need to run your code earlier in the web page? For example, are the buttons being created and added to the page before you run your buttons(); function?

Comment: Are you checking if "Start" button is clicked after you do `if (!isset($_SESSION["buttons"])){$_SESSION["buttons"]='disabled';}`

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL My assignment is creating a BlackJack game in PHP, if i would use javascript now, i bet there were plenty of things that i could do better using javascript or flash even.

Comment: @ElefantPhace Thats what my example did right? It echo'd a different session output in the html buttons to disable them or enable them?

Comment: @Djave No, the html form is first thing that shows up. The first line of the entire code is `session_start();` and the second line in my case being the `!isset session buttons` and after the button click it will run buttons(); for the first time

Comment: @Subin It standard sets the buttons on disabled. As i explained in my code `if (!isset($_SESSION["buttons"])){$_SESSION["buttons"]='disabled';}` means the buttons will be disabled upon entering the page, and then IF the start button is clicked it will change the session to '' meaning the buttons should get enabled.

Comment: No. You're just setting variables. In talking about your HTML inputs. You need to set the attribute on the buttons

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way to to do is setting up a numeric variable.

Lets say, it is $hands_played;
thus, the starting hand will be 0;

so, set your session to check is $hands_played = 0, if so, then add attribute disabled="disabled" to the button, if more than 0, don't.

but, to be honest, please use Javascript.